# Can someone help me with this inequality proof?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

> Prove that for each pair of real numbers $a < b$ there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a <\frac{m}{2^n}< b$.

---

So far I've tried using the well-ordering principle but I'm not sure if that is a valid method as I keep getting stuck. If anyone can help me that would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please don't use the `proof-writing` tag when your goal is simply to prove an assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Because $b > a$, then $2^n(b-a)$ tends to $+\infty$. Therefore, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$2^N(b-a) > 1$$

Now let
$$m = \lfloor 2^N a + 1 \rfloor$$ One has
$$a=\frac{2^Na}{2^N}<\frac{m}{2^N} \leq \frac{2^N a + 1}{2^N} < \frac{2^N b}{2^N} = b$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Show that the difference $(b-a)\cdot 2^n$ exceeds $2$ for some $n$. What can you conclude ?